# Conditional React Routers

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react router to navigate between components and pages
the two components that is shown in every page is the  `<Navbar />`  and the  `<Footer />`
but conditionally I want to hide these two Components when I navigate to `<LoginPage />`
this is all my router.

---

```
 return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />           
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Routes>
        <Route index element={<FirstLoad />} />
        <Route path="/LoginPage" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
        <Route path="/DepartmentProfile" element={<DepartmentProfile />} />
        <Route path="/*" element={<FirstLoad />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
```

---

I have tried different conditional functions but not worked, once worked but the other components didn't open,
simply want to hide the Navbar and the Footer when I navigate to LoginPage